# Settings->Users throws "Uncaught Promise > Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'string')" error (Odoo 16.0 Community Edition)

Tags: odoo

When I go to Settings and try to open Users, I get the following error message:

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'string')

Nothing more happens (users won't open and I cannot see, which fields I'm lacking or what is wrong with the user).

Answer (score 1):

Which module did you install last before noticing the error?

It is worth noting that this error is more prone in the latest version (Odoo 16) which is still receiving bug fixes.

In the absence of more information, the solution will be to execute the following steps:

1. Go to `addons\web\static\src\legacy\legacy_load_views.js`
2. Look for `const fieldName = node.getAttribute("name");` code (usually on line 64)
3. Place `console.log(fieldName);` after it.
4. Restart your server (not necessary but recommended)
5. Refresh your browser
6. On your browser developer tools, make sure cache is disabled, and go to console;
7. On odoo, try going to **Settings**;
8. A list of fields will be printed on your console, the last one before the error is usually the culprit. In the sample output below, the culprit is the `pos_epson_printer_ip` field

```
...
module_pos_six
web.assets_backend.min.js:6534 pos_other_devices
web.assets_backend.min.js:6534 pos_epson_printer_ip
web.assets_backend.min.js:659 TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'string')
    at web.assets_backend.min.js:6534:234
    at traverse (web.assets_backend.min.js:6529:200)
    at web.assets_backend.min.js:6529:242
    at Function.each (web.assets_common.min.js:171:149)
    at traverse (web.assets_backend.min.js:6529:211)
    at web.assets_backend.min.js:6529:242
    at Function.each (web.assets_common.min.js:171:149)
    at traverse (web.assets_backend.min.js:6529:211)
    at web.assets_backend.min.js:6529:242
    at Function.each (web.assets_common.min.js:171:149)
```

9. Install the module the fields belong to. In the sample output above, we need to install **pos_epson_printer** module.
10. Try accessing the **Settings**.
11. Repeat steps 7–10 until you can access **Settings**.

Comment: you're my man, you save my time. Heroooo, thank you so much